# Changing menu label to post name for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, admin-menu, labels

I have a custom post type. I would like the user to see the post name when they select the custom post type in the admin menu to edit it. I currently have this:

```
$labels = array(
    'name' => _x("Licenses", "post type general name"),
    'singular_name' => _x("License", "post type singular name"),
    'menu_name' => 'License',
    'add_new' => _x("Add New", "resource item"),
    'add_new_item' => __("Add New License"),
    'edit_item' => __("Edit Resource"),
    'new_item' => __("New Resource"),
    'view_item' => __("View Resource"),
    'search_items' => __("Search Resource"),
    'not_found' =>  __("No Resources Found"),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __("No Resources Found in Trash"),
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
);
```

So in place of "Edit Resource", I would like it to display the post name.

Comment: The postname? Meaning the current post they're editing? or the post type?

Comment: The current post they are editing. So the post name would appear at the top.

Comment: S you want the post title to be in the menu name instead of Edit Resource?

Comment: That is correct.